# Build java project using jars into one jar (command line)

Tags: java, jar

In Intellij, I'm able to "build an artifact" which allows me to create a jar file, even though my project uses other jar files (like drivers). Traditionally, I would compile a project with jar dependencies by putting them in my classpath like so:

```
javac -cp .:dependency.jar Main.java
```

and then be able to run `Main` by doing:

```
java -cp .:dependency.jar Main
```

My question is, how do I create a jar file file with this new `Main`? I can do:

```
jar cvf Main.jar Main.java
```

which will create a jar file, but it doesn't run and says:

```
no main manifest attribute, in Main.jar
```

I'd like to know how to package my other jar dependencies into on executable jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**: Using Maven plug-in if you are using maven:

```
       <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>Path.to.your.main.class</mainClass>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

**Option 2**: Using spring boot to create fat jar. Which includes all your dependent jar files. Make sure you include spring boot dependency.

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

**Option 3:**  Without any help of maven and Spring:

Create a manifest.txt file with the following content:

```
Main-Class: path.to.your.main.class
```

To create jar use command : `jar -cvfm Application.jar manifest.txt /path/to/*.class`

Comment: I'm trying option 3 but when executing `java -jar Application.jar` I'm getting `Error could not find or load main class`